# Text-area reading HTML not as text?

Tags: jquery

I `.append` a string created by some jQuery, the string generates HTML markup, when I insert it into the text-area it shows in firebug, but will not show in the actual text-area. I assume it's doing this because it reads it as HTML and not text.

Here is a example.

```
    var classesHtmlString = jQuery(".generator-attr:checked").map(function () {
    var $this = jQuery(this);
        return $this.val();  
    }).get().join(" "); 

    var htmlString = '<div class="'+classesHtmlString+'">';

    jQuery('#generator-html-result').val(htmlString);

    var shortcodeHTML = jQuery('#generator-html-result').val();
```

Then I `.append` it to the text-area I want, I will provide more if necessary but I think perhaps appending HTML to a text-area doesn't allow it to read it as text. I googled this but couldn't find much.

Comment: can u make a fiddle ?

Comment: Well I just refined my google search and realized I could just use `.html()`, problem with that it clears existing html inside the text-area

Comment: instead of val() try using html()

Comment: @LimH. the HTML string gets stored inside an input, so I have to use `.val()`

Comment: It is appending to the textarea but is invisable... there is an opacity on the markup in firebug

Comment: @MichaelJosephAubry can you post the code where you use "append"?

Comment: I changed the code to be regular text and it appends fine.. but it's just due to it being HTML that causes problems..

Comment: I wrote a fiddle here http://jsfiddle.net/nQErc/229/ you see it clears the default value.. I would like to keep the default

Answer (score 0):

1. textarea's are treated differently.  They, technically, do not use `.val` for the input of it's content.  Instead of appending it, just write it into the textarea, since I'm pretty sure you don't want to append it, you want to write content to it.
2. Also, for the sake of being proper, lets escape the html as well.

Change this:

```
jQuery('#generator-html-result').val(htmlString);
```

To this:

```
jQuery('#generator-html-result').text(htmlString).html();
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nX8Dq/5/)

Of if you want the variable `shortcodeHTML`

`var shortcodeHTML = jQuery('#generator-html-result').text(htmlString).html();`

Comment: Sorry if I wasn't clear enough, I mention I use these methods, the main concern became it overwrites the existing text-area values.. I wrote a fiddle to combat that http://jsfiddle.net/nQErc/232/ BUT now I am curious to know how I can append to where the cursor is...

Answer (score 0):

Jquery uses elements property internally so if we go this way, then textarea is something like this:

```
<textarea id="foo">HTML TEST</textarea>
```

and normal input's(text boxes, checkbox etc) are like :

`<input type="text" id="bar" value="HTML TEST AGAIN"/>`

So if we you `.val()` on input, it will work perfectly fine as input element have `value` property in them while syntax of textarea is similar to '`div`, `span`, etc', so to fill/extract the textarea value(as per your perception), it should be present between `<textarea></textarea>`

For that jquery has `'.html() & .text()'` methods. Hope you are clear when should we use `.val(), .html()/.text()` methods.